# I cannot modify entity values

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have installed the Views Bulk Operations module and am looking to use it to mass edit my content. However, when I select a few nodes to edit and select Modify Entity Values and click Execute, I get taken to a page that simply says, "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Unfortunately, my server logs and Drupal logs come up empty as to what error may have occurred.

Additionally, it seems like when I select Modify Entity Values, I should see an option for what entity value I am looking to modify but I am never presented with that option.

As an alternative, I found a guide that demonstrates how to replicate this behavior with Rules components but I have not yet been able to figure out how to make this work with taxonomy terms.

I would prefer however, to simply get the Views Bulk Operations to work as I would expect.

Comment: What happens if you choose just one of the selected items and go to its edit page? Does the edit page save successfully? Does it give any errors?

Comment: It's the same error whether I select one or ten.

Comment: I meant not through VBO, go directly to one of selected item's edit page and try. I am trying to see if you have some kind of issue without VBO involved first.

Comment: Oh whoops. When I edit an individual page I'm able to make edits as you would expect.

Comment: Can you then re-configure VBO with minimal settings (to change, for example, just one field value) select just one item and see it goes through. If it does then start adding more change fields one by one. If not then something is wrong with VBO or its settings and you might want to re-install it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I was trying to do what you suggested, I realized that the view was created via the admin_views module. I uninstalled and reinstalled both but the problem persists.

Comment: admin_views could have its own limitations, so not to interfere with its settings, why don't you create another view without admin_views

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I did as you suggested and run in to the same error.

Comment: Are there any places other than the reports page and my apache server logs that might spit out an error message?

Comment: I've disabled all modules except Core and the modules required view Views Bulk Operations and I still get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get this working. Under show available tokens, I previously had selected -- All --.

I have since changed this to be just the fields that I'm interested in having edited and it works as expected now.

My theory is that I have a lot of content types with a lot of fields and it was hitting some sort of memory error. However, I never saw an error reported.